# any middleware in django to perform the abilities of security.yml in symfony2?

Tags: python, django, symfony, django-middleware

Can i declare the auth for all the apis in django,
group wise from one file just like [security.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html) allows us in symfony2

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the package [django-stronghold](https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold). It allows you to require login for all views.